# Find values of $a$ and $b$ if they are both real

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

$1+i$ is root of $z^2+(a+2i)z+5-ib=0$, and we're supposed to find $a$ and $b$. They're both real.

I'm in a bit of a pickle, through long division I figured that $5-ib+(1+i)(3i+a+1)=0$ (Someone, please correct me if I did something weird because it looks too dank to work with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

$$5-ib+(1+i)(3i+a+1)=0$$

can be rewritten:

$$(a + 3) + i (4 + a - b) = 0 + 0i$$

From this we get a system of linear equations:

$$a + 3 = 0$$
$$4 + a - b = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

A possible approach:

- Substitute $z=1+i$.
- Compare the real part and the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+i)^2=1+2i-1=2i
$$

Substitute $z=1+i$:
$$
2i+(a+2i)(1+i)+5−ib=0
$$
$$
2i+a+2i+ai-2+5-bi=0
$$
$$
(a+3)+(a+4-b)i=0
$$
Both real and imaginary parts must be  zero, so
$$
a+3=0
$$
$$
a+4-b=0
$$

$$
a=-3
$$
$$
b=1
$$

Could be some calculation errors, but the idea is the main thing.